# Delete everything that comes after second numeric subfolder

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

```
data <- data.table(column1 = paste0("/url/", c("xyz", "dsas", "ffdsfsd", "fsfddsfds", "ffdfd"))) %>%
                     mutate(column1 = paste0(column1, "/app/"),
                            column1 = paste0(column1, sample(5)),
                            column1 = paste0(column1, "app"))
```

I want to delete whatever comes after the second subdirectory. I tried the method `separate` but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be either

```
setDT(data)[, column1 := sub("\\/[^/]*$", "", column1)]
data$column1
#[1] "/url/xyz/app"       "/url/dsas/app"      "/url/ffdsfsd/app"   "/url/fsfddsfds/app" "/url/ffdfd/app"
```

Or

```
setDT(data)[, column1 := sub("\\/[^/]*\\/[^/]*$", "", column1)]
data$column1
#[1] "/url/xyz"       "/url/dsas"      "/url/ffdsfsd"   "/url/fsfddsfds" "/url/ffdfd"
```